# Interpreting a 3rd party JSON file into a PHP form

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am trying to work with a pre-made library to configure SIP phones. They appear to have used JSON for the templates, and I am in unfamiliar territory. There are many makes/models and some have multiple templates. I would like to be able to get the contents of the template and convert it to a php form. I am unsure of how to code for the different section names. I would like to write one PHP function that does it all regardless of the template file used.
Here are 2 of the templates I am working with:

```
{
  "template_data":{
    "category":[
      {
        "name":"keys",
        "subcategory":[
          {
            "name":"Soft Keys (9480i\/6755i\/6757i)",
            "item":[
              {
                "description":"Soft Keys (9480i\/6755i\/6757i)",
                "type":"loop",
                "loop_start":"1",
                "loop_end":"18",
                "data":{
                  "item":[
                    {
                      "variable":"$softkey_type",
                      "default_value":"empty",
                      "category":"keys",
                      "description":"Soft Key {$count} Type",
                      "type":"list",
                      "data":[
                        {
                          "text":"Empty",
                          "value":"empty"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Services",
                          "value":"services"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Speed Dial",
                          "value":"speeddial"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Line",
                          "value":"line"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"BLF",
                          "value":"blf"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"List",
                          "value":"list"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Do Not Disturb",
                          "value":"dnd"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"XML URL",
                          "value":"xml"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"BLF Transfer",
                          "value":"blfxfer"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Intercom",
                          "value":"icom"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Pickup",
                          "value":"pickup"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Flash",
                          "value":"flash"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Special Prefix Code",
                          "value":"spre"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Park",
                          "value":"park"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Directory",
                          "value":"directory"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Callers",
                          "value":"callers"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "variable":"$softkey_label",
                      "default_value":"",
                      "description":"Soft Key {$count} Label",
                      "type":"input"
                    },
                    {
                      "variable":"$softkey_value",
                      "default_value":"",
                      "description":"Soft Key {$count} Value",
                      "type":"input"
                    },
                    {
                      "variable":"$softkey_states",
                      "default_value":"Any",
                      "description":"Soft Key {$count} States",
                      "type":"list",
                      "data":[
                        {
                          "text":"Any",
                          "value":"connected,idle,incoming,outgoing"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Connected",
                          "value":"connected"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Idle",
                          "value":"idle"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Incoming",
                          "value":"incoming"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Outgoing",
                          "value":"outgoing"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Idle or Incoming",
                          "value":"idle,incoming"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"Connected or Outgoing",
                          "value":"connected,outgoing"
                        },
                        {
                          "text":"None (Hide Button)",
                          "value":[

                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "type":"break"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and here is another:

```
{
  "template_data":{
    "category":[
      {
        "name":"keys",
        "subcategory":[
          {
            "name":"Multi Function Keys",
            "item":[
              {
                "variable":"$key_mode_01",
                "default_value":"",
                "description":"Key 1 Mode",
                "type":"list",
                "data":[
                  {
                    "text":"Speed Dial",
                    "value":"0"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"BLF",
                    "value":"1"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Presence Watcher",
                    "value":"2"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Eventlist BLF",
                    "value":"3"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_name_01",
                "default_value":"Speed Dial 1",
                "description":"Key Name",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$speed_dial_01",
                "default_value":"*01",
                "description":"Value #1",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "type":"break"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_mode_02",
                "default_value":"",
                "description":"Key 2 Mode",
                "type":"list",
                "data":[
                  {
                    "text":"Speed Dial",
                    "value":"0"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"BLF",
                    "value":"1"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Presence Watcher",
                    "value":"2"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Eventlist BLF",
                    "value":"3"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_name_02",
                "default_value":"Speed Dial 2",
                "description":"Key Name",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$speed_dial_02",
                "default_value":"*02",
                "description":"Value #2",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "type":"break"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_mode_03",
                "default_value":"",
                "description":"Key 3 Mode",
                "type":"list",
                "data":[
                  {
                    "text":"Speed Dial",
                    "value":"0"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"BLF",
                    "value":"1"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Presence Watcher",
                    "value":"2"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Eventlist BLF",
                    "value":"3"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_name_03",
                "default_value":"Speed Dial 3",
                "description":"Key Name",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$speed_dial_03",
                "default_value":"*03",
                "description":"Value #3",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "type":"break"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_mode_04",
                "default_value":"",
                "description":"Key 4 Mode",
                "type":"list",
                "data":[
                  {
                    "text":"Speed Dial",
                    "value":"0"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"BLF",
                    "value":"1"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Presence Watcher",
                    "value":"2"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Eventlist BLF",
                    "value":"3"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_name_04",
                "default_value":"Speed Dial 4",
                "description":"Key Name",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$speed_dial_04",
                "default_value":"*04",
                "description":"Value #4",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "type":"break"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_mode_05",
                "default_value":"",
                "description":"Key 5 Mode",
                "type":"list",
                "data":[
                  {
                    "text":"Speed Dial",
                    "value":"0"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"BLF",
                    "value":"1"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Presence Watcher",
                    "value":"2"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Eventlist BLF",
                    "value":"3"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_name_05",
                "default_value":"Speed Dial 5",
                "description":"Key Name",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$speed_dial_05",
                "default_value":"*05",
                "description":"Value #5",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "type":"break"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_mode_06",
                "default_value":"",
                "description":"Key 6 Mode",
                "type":"list",
                "data":[
                  {
                    "text":"Speed Dial",
                    "value":"0"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"BLF",
                    "value":"1"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Presence Watcher",
                    "value":"2"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Eventlist BLF",
                    "value":"3"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_name_06",
                "default_value":"Speed Dial 6",
                "description":"Key Name",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$speed_dial_06",
                "default_value":"*06",
                "description":"Value #6",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "type":"break"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_mode_07",
                "default_value":"",
                "description":"Key 7 Mode",
                "type":"list",
                "data":[
                  {
                    "text":"Speed Dial",
                    "value":"0"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"BLF",
                    "value":"1"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Presence Watcher",
                    "value":"2"
                  },
                  {
                    "text":"Eventlist BLF",
                    "value":"3"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "variable":"$key_name_07",
                "default_value":"Speed Dial 7",
                "description":"Key Name",
                "type":"input"
              },
              {
                "variable":"$speed_dial_07",
                "default_value":"*07",
                "description":"Value #7",
                "type":"input"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It looks like this was designed to do exactly what I want, I just don't know how to begin. I am able to retrieve the data from the template files, but from there am lost. I have tried working with the json_decode, but the output doesn't seem any friendlier to work with. I have also tried using php to get the contents of the template and then using javascript to dismantle it. This is sort of working, but would require more static variables for each file, and if the provider of the files changes something, it could require more time editing. If anyone knows of the simplest way to approach this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use handlebars.js to display the info. Look here:

```
http://handlebarsjs.com/
```

I use it daily and its as simple as:

```
<tr>
<td>{{clock_number}}</td>
<td style="width: 150px;">{{employee_name}}</td>
<td>{{hourly_wage}}</td>
<td><a href='employee.php?clock_number={{clock_number}}'>Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

Really good free course to help you get going:

```
https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid statically coding for each possible variable name if possible. In a perfect world, I would only have to look for certain variable settings (radio, list, input, etc) and then show the appropriate form input type based on that value, but I don't know what the keys will be from file to file. To make matters more interesting, I don't know that the values will even be consistent.

Comment: hmm tricky, probably anything I would suggest you have already thought of.